# VueJs v-Model Binding with Hidden Component not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I am developing a SPA application in Vue. I have a wizard in the wizard I have a component for each step. All the components are adding at the start and their mounted and created method/event is executing when the application starts.

I am using the event bus & when I move to the next step of wizard I emit the event and catch the event on the respective step.

Note: Component is hidden at the start and when it shows it will not have the updated data or even data in input fields.

Code of the component of the 2nd step is

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="marshaCode">MARSHA Code:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control field-ml-15" v-model="marshaCode" placeholder="Enter Marsha Code" readonly />
            <input type="text" class="form-control field-ml-15":value="marshaCode" placeholder="Enter Marsha Code" readonly />
            <p>{{marshaCode}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>


<script>
  import { EventBus } from "../../shared/eventbus.js";

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        marshaCode:"On Load Code"
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      EventBus.$on('showSurvey', () => {
        this.marshaCode="On Show Code"
      });
    },
  }
</script>
```

Now when this component will show the P tag will have **"On Load Code"** But in both the fields there will be no data.

How can I rebind, re-render or update the data?

Comment: how do you show/hide components?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I am using the following Jquery Plugin. Each Component is a step of the jquery plugin. Steps are added at the start when applications start & the first step is visible. 
http://www.jquery-steps.com/Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use `vue` to show/hide the component using `v-if` or `v-show`.  It can't do it's job if another library is messing with the DOM.

```html
  <section v-if='showMyComponent'>
```

or

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" v-if='showMyComponent'>
            <input type="text" class="form-control field-ml-15" v-model="marshaCode" placeholder="Enter Marsha Code" readonly />
            <input type="text" class="form-control field-ml-15":value="marshaCode" placeholder="Enter Marsha Code" readonly />
            <p>{{marshaCode}}</p>
          </div>
```

And set `showMyComponent` to a computed or data property.  Then remove the logic to show/hide from your other library.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `this.marshaCode="On Show Code"` when mounted.

```
mounted() {
  this.marshaCode="On Show Code"
  console.log(EventBus)
  EventBus.$on('showSurvey', () => {
    this.marshaCode="On Show Code"
  });
}
```

An example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-8l2lg.